# Stop the procedure if there are no values ​in the A1 to the end of the column

Tags: vba

I have a problem with this routine, if in column A from A2 to the end of column there are no written cells, I would like to stop the sub but I can't understand how to set

```
Sub test()
Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long, j As Long, arr
  Set sh = Sheets(2)
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  arr = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastR).Value
  i = 1
  For j = 2 To UBound(arr)
     If i > 0 Then arr(j, 1) = arr(j, 1) & "-"
     i = i + 1
     If i = 8 Then i = 0
  Next j
  sh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr), 1).Value = arr
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Call Copia
End Sub
```

Comment: `If arr(j, 1) = "" Then Exit Sub`. Immediately after `For j = 2 To UBound(arr)`. Now, do you want preliminarily check if such gaps exist, or le the code doing something and exit at the first such gap?

Comment: Doesn't work, type mismatch error

Comment: Where did you place the recommended line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `WorksheetFunction` to count the non-empty cell and use `Exit Sub` to stop the procedure

```
Sub test2()
Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long, j As Long, arr
  Set sh = Sheets(2)
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  arr = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastR).Value
  i = 1
  
  If WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range(sh.Range("A2"), sh.Range("A2").End(xlDown))) = 0 Then
  
     Exit Sub
     
  End If
  
  For j = 2 To UBound(arr)
     If i > 0 Then arr(j, 1) = arr(j, 1) & "-"
     i = i + 1
     If i = 8 Then i = 0
  Next j
  sh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr), 1).Value = arr
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```